# Japanese 気分転換 in Cantonese?

Tags: cantonese

Is there an expression in Cantonese with roughly the same meaning as the Japanese 気分転換 (I guess it's 氣分轉換 in Chinese characters)?
I would include an English translation but something might get lost in translation, so I'll just refer to [these examples](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E6%B0%97%E5%88%86%E8%BB%A2%E6%8F%9B&ref=sa).

Comment: I don't know about Cantonese specifically, but you might take a look at [耳目一新](http://www.iciba.com/%E8%80%B3%E7%9B%AE%E4%B8%80%E6%96%B0/) and [面目一新](http://www.iciba.com/%E9%9D%A2%E7%9B%AE%E4%B8%80%E6%96%B0/)

Comment: @StumpyJoePete It seems going for a walk or having cold beer after long work hours are also 気分転換, but there is nothing 耳目一新 in them. I can't think of a better Chinese word though...

Comment: Any reason why this has to be specifically Cantonese? Idioms are usually the same across all Chinese dialects/topolects, if that's what you are looking for that is.

Comment: @deutschZuid If it really is the same then of course it doesn't matter. But seeing how it's not borrowed from Chinese and used more casually than a proverb in Japanese (I think), I thought it could be something more colloquial.

Comment: "换口气", "喘口气", "透透气", "放松一下", "稍事休息", "歇息一会儿" are those I can think of closer to "気分転換" in Janpanese.

Comment: @gaidal There is no 换人一心, Did you want to say 焕然一新? It is used to describe an object being refreshed, e.g. the car is 焕然一新 after car wash. It's not used for living things or activities.

Comment: @NS.X. Oops! Never thought about how that's actually spelled. I see, then it doesn't work for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if this this phrase means

release your stress and get a little rest, (maybe take some breath to help you relex ?)

there is some Chinese expression “缓口气”

Comment: The original expression is something like what you wrote, but also means "for a change" and "to refresh oneself". This one only seems to has the "relax" part of the meaning, which is kind of close. At least it does appear to be used in Cantonese.

Comment: I think it's too difficult to find a exact word in Chinese which has all the meanings. you may use different words depends on conditions.

Comment: Is 缓口气 a Cantonese expression?

Comment: yes, if you are really stressed out, you can say that, it equals you say, give me a relief. And also in Chinese you can say "缓一缓", and "缓口气" just happen to have the meaning of get another breath

Comment: You're right that it's too difficult, and this is the closest one now that it's confirmed Cantonese. :)

Answer (score 1):

轉換心情 I think.

There are lots of Japanese words that have totally different meanings from Chinese words though they uses similar characters.

In your question, 気分 in 気分転換 often meaning feeling or mood in Japanese, but in Chinese, there is no such a word 氣分, but a similar word 氣氛, which means atmosphere or ambiance.

The word structure is different, too. In Chinese we won't say 心情轉換 (object then verb) but 轉換心情 (verb then object), because Chinese is a [subject-verb-object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject%E2%80%93verb%E2%80%93object) language, but Japanese is an [SOV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject%E2%80%93object%E2%80%93verb) language.

Comment: I always thought of 気分転換 as a noun-noun, a "feeling refresher". In Japanese it needs a "suru" to be a verb. Yes, Japanese has many unique expressions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just say "放松一下".

Comment: This does actually get pretty close, although it doesn't have the same sense of "for a change" or "refresh oneself". I could accept this answer until there's something closer, but is this really used in colloquial Cantonese too? It has a very Mandarin feel.

Comment: It is used in colloquial Cantonese. Quite frequently in fact.